# FindControl (ImageButton) inside a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I hope someone could help me with this. I wasn't able to find the ImageButton control inside the ListView, it always gives me **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error.

The scenario is, if I checked the checkbox, I wanted the imagebutton to change its' image. The Checkbox does not reside inside the Listview ItemTemplate. Here's my code behind for the checkbox_checkchanged event:

```
   if (cb.Checked)
    {
        foreach (Control c in lv.Controls)
        {
            ImageButton btndel = (ImageButton)c.FindControl("btnDelete");
            btndel.ImageUrl = "~/images/activate.png";
        }
     }
```

Note: I used ForEach Loop thinking that the btnDelete button appears several times in my Listview.

Comment: FYI, on [SO], you don't need to put things like "C# ASP.net" in your titles. We use tags for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Checkbox is outside of the ListView, the best way would be to use ListView's [ItemCreated-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcreated.aspx):

```
protected void LV_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  // Retrieve the current item.
  ListViewItem item = e.Item;

  // Verify if the item is a data item.
  if (item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem && cb.Checked)
  {
    ImageButton btndel = (ImageButton)item.FindControl("btnDelete");
    btndel.ImageUrl = "~/images/activate.png";
  }
}
```

You don't need to handle the Checkbox' CheckedChanged-Event but only need to add the OnItemCreated-handler on your aspx markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LV" OnItemCreated="LV_ItemCreated" ... />
```

On this way you prevent multiple iterations of the ListView-Items. ItemCreated will anyway be called implicitely on every postback to recreate the ListView-Items.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response!

Tim, the code you gave is exactly the same i found in ASP.net Forum replied by Dwhite
[http://forums.asp.net/t/1163895.aspx][1]


  [1]: http://forums.asp.net/t/1163895.aspx

It's Working now. Thanks you very much guys! I really appreciate it

Comment: @bounce: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Glad that i could help. Have a look [here on how you can accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Tim, i'm trying to understand your code specifically on the condition: if(item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem) ,can you explain what we are comparing here and what's the purpose of this?

Comment: @Bounce: Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.itemtype.aspx) to see what a `ListViewItem.ItemType` is.

Answer (score 0):

before casting you should check if the result of FindControl is null or of proper type.

Try to call FindControl also inside the Controls of the `c` object because it could be the control you are looking for is down one more level of nesting ( so inside the ListViewItem ), actually, you can loop inside the `lv.Items` and do a FindControl in there...

Answer (score 0):

```
For each (ListViewDataItem c in lv.items)...
```